# Node.js http requests and cookies with http module

Tags: node.js, http

How do I use http module to make GET requests with a query string and cookies?

`GET someurl?test=one`

Cookies: name=john; name1=mary;

Comment: Have you tried something?  What exactly isn't working?  The `http` docs are pretty clear, I think.  Note that cookies are sent as a header.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You might want to take a look at the [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework and docs, as it's a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var url_parser = require("url");

var url = "someurl?test=one";
var url_parts = url_parser.parse(url);

var options = {host: url_parts.hostname, port: url_parts.port|80, path: url_parts.path};

var request = http.request(options, function(response) {

    //do something with the response

}).on('error',function(e){
    //error happened
});

request.setHeader( 'cookie', YOUR_COOKIE );

request.end();
```